# PHP shopping cart array, get cart from session, group by category and count

Tags: php, arrays, shopping-cart

I'm building a shopping cart using a free script I found.  I am trying to count the items in each category to determine shipping charges.  Categories are numeric in the database 1,2,3, etc. The script I have groups the items by item number (code) when displayed, and I can't seem to figure how to group by category and produce a total amount of items in each category.  I'm pretty terrible with arrays. Thanks for the help.

```
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 
                'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 
                'category'=>$productByCode[0]["category"],
                'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"],
                'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"],
                'image'=>$productByCode[0]["image"]));
            
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k) {
                                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
                                }
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }
    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;  
}
}
```

Here is the code to show items in the cart:

```
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        $item_price = $item["quantity"]*$item["price"];
        
echo $item['image'];
echo $item["name"];
echo $item["code"];
echo #item["category"];
echo $item["quantity"];
echo $item["price"];

}

$total_quantity += $item["quantity"];
$total_price += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
```

Comment: How about accumulating these total values inside the loop?

Comment: I tried that first, but the script groups by unique item number. So I couldn’t figure how to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I took a step back and kept it simple.  I went back and created a category counter before the foreach loop. In the loop I checked which category was registering and added the quantity of item to the counter for that category. Simple but it works.